# WebdriverIO testing in docker

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, webdriver, dockerfile

I'm interested in accessing the app running on one container by webdriverio to test. When i run locally, I do the following which works fine

```
yarn start // starts the app on htpp://localhost:3000
yarn test  // runs wdio test which access the htpp://localhost:3000
```

webdriverio test example

```
it("check if submit button works", function(done) {
        browser.url('http://0.0.0.0:3000');
        var title = browser.getTitle();
        browser.click('#submitButton');
        console.log('App Title is: ' + title);
        browser.pause(3000);
    });
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.10.0
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN yarn
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
app:
  build: .
  command: "yarn start"
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
  expose:
    - "3000"

selenium:
  image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome:3.11.0-californium'
  expose:
    - "4444"
  links:
    - app
  log_driver: "none"

test:
  build: .
  command: "yarn test --host selenium"
  links:
    - selenium
```

I would like to run the app in one container and then also run the test which will access the app for testing

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: Did you manage to do such a thing? I'm trying to

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is possible. We used to have our test environment running in docker containers and the site is accessible in our local machine. Likewise, you may have to establish network connection between the containers.